# Managing Google Assistant for the enterprise

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-home, smart-tv, google-assist-api

We are exploring the use of Google Home and LG Google Assistant TVs for an enterprise application. This would require managing hundreds of devices in a single building. Amazon Alexa has "Amazon for Business" for doing this for Alexa devices.

Is there anything similar for Google Assistant devices? Is there an efficient way to manage hundreds of devices? Can device management be done remotely?

We would like to use Google Assistant devices because of superior AI technology but feel we might have to use Alexa because of the need to manage so many devices.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

An action built for the Google Assistant runs entirely in the cloud, so you shouldn't need to worry about device management. The same action can be accessed by multiple devices at the same time, via HTTP requests.

For more information, check out Google's codelab [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-1/#1).

Comment: Hi Max... thanks for the input. Each google assistant device... in this case an LG TV still has to be configured and managed. So it's not managing the action... it's managing the device. Image 500 LG TVs in an office building that all need a Google Assistant configuration change from time to time.